# How do I get frames one by one from the video in Qt framework?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I got a video input with QMediaPlayer and then I wanted to read frames one by one and process all frames with other vision algorithms. But I didn't know how do I get frames one by one from the video and access each pixel of the frame...

In OpenCV library, I'm easily able to solve that problem with cv::VideoCapture and cv::Mat.

```
cv::VideoCapture capture(filename);
cv::Mat img;

capture >> img; // 'img' contains the first frame of the video.
capture >> img; // 'img' contains the second frame of the video.
```

If someone has already handle with this kind of problem, please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using OpenCV if it works for you of course :)

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own implementation of the [`QAbstractVideoSurface`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractvideosurface.html) and override its 
[`present`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractvideosurface.html#present) method to handle the video frame by frame.
Then you will have to set the video output of the `QMediaPlayer` via  [`setVideoOutput`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#setVideoOutput-2).

For details how to access the frame data you should consult the [`QVideoFrame`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion: you could use OpenCV. That would make things easier to play videos and process them without QImage->Mat conversion.

In order to process videos with OpenCV + Qt you must create a QThread connected to a QTimer signal. The QTimer signal emits every few milliseconds signals to a slot in the worker thread to fetch the next video frame from VideoCapture and work on the data.

Comment: With [`QVideoFrame::bits()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html#bits) you don't get a `QImage`, but raw data, so one could plug the OpenCV  code into the overridden `QAbstractVideoSurface::present ` method and avoid the `QTimer`.